# Display user details after successfully login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, authorization

I'm writing a asp.net mvc3 project with bundle of SQL Server 2012 and EF. I'm added the authorization to this project. It's create user successfully, but after creating I want that it's redirect to page where display all info about student, but I'm not understand how I make do this. All what I found it's use in my View is something like this:

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

But that's not enough for me. I was try to send the id, but it return me an error. Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(Student student)
    {
        Register(student.Username, student.Password, student.Email, true, student.FirstName, student.LastName);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Membership", new {id == student.StudentId});
    }

    public static MembershipCreateStatus Register(string Username, string Password, string Email, bool IsApproved, string FirstName, string LastName) {
        MembershipCreateStatus CreateStatus;
        System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(Username, Password, Email, null, null, IsApproved, null, out CreateStatus);

        if (CreateStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success) {
            using (UniversityContext Context = new UniversityContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString)) {
                Student User = Context.Students.FirstOrDefault(Usr => Usr.Username == Username);
                User.FirstName = FirstName;
                User.LastName = LastName;
                Context.SaveChanges();
            }

            if (IsApproved) {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Username, false);
            }
        }

        return CreateStatus;
    }

public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var model = context.Students
            .Include(x => x.Universities)
            .Include(x => x.FieldStudies)
            .Include(x => x.StudyModes)
            .Include(x => x.StudentDegrees)
            .Include(x => x.EntryMonths)
            .Include(x => x.Genders)
            .Include(x => x.EnglishLanguages)
            .Include(x => x.RussianLanguages)
            .Include(x => x.LatvianLanguages)
            .Include(x => x.OtherLans)
            .Include(x => x.OtherLanNexts)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.StudentId == id);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Views is out of the box Create/Detail with strongly typed View by my Student Model, Any Ideas?

**EDIT**

I'm add to my View next lines of code, but I think it's not a correct solution

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Entities.Student>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SecondLayout.cshtml";
    var name = @User.Identity.Name;
}

<h2>Index</h2>


Hello there @name

<fieldset>
    <legend>Student</legend>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.Username == name)
        {
            <div class="display-label">
                 @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Username)
            </div>
            <div class="display-field">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Username)
            </div>

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ActionResult Index(int id)` returns only one object or null (`.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StudentId == id);`) But you typed your view as a list of objects `IEnumerable<Models.Entities.Student>.`

So,

1) Change top definition to `@model Models.Entities.Student`

2) Now you may access all properties you need using `@Model` statment:

```
@Model.username
@Model.email
@Model.FirstName
@Model.SeconName
....
```